How to handle an included file with DSC comments included?
In a PostScript document, which should adhere to the PostScript Language Document Structuring Conventions, there is an (includedfile) run command. This included file contains itself some DSC comments, like %%Page:.
What is the right way to go in the main PostScript document ?
Where should be
%%DocumentNeededResources: file includedfile ?
Is this sufficient ?

I'm not convinced that a PostScript program which uses 'run' to execute another PostScript program which includes the showpage operator can be DSC compliant. The IncludeResource and NeededResources comments are intended for Resources in a PostScript sense; Fonts, images, Forms etc. All the pages should be included in the body, I don't think you can run an external program which doesn't follow the EPS rules.
